# How To Use RegEx Expression with InSTR

Tags: regex, vb.net

So wha ti'm looking to do is scrub an html file for anything that resembles an IP address or any set of numbers for that matter. Normally what I would do is just using things like string.split to split out the html around areas that I want to search. What im looking to do is be able to essentially search a large amount of characters for anything that matches this reg ex pattern. Any ideas on how to do that?

```
Dim pattern As String = "^(\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]):(\d{1,4}|[0-5]\d\d\d\d|[0-5]\d\d\d\d|6[0-4]\d\d\d|65[0-4]\d\d|655[0-2]\d|6553[0-5])$"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like below and then iterate over the matches..

```
Dim pattern As String = "^(\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]):(\d{1,4}|[0-5]\d\d\d\d|[0-5]\d\d\d\d|6[0-4]\d\d\d|65[0-4]\d\d|655[0-2]\d|6553[0-5])$"

Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(someHTML, pattern)

For Each ipMatch As Match In matches
    Console.WriteLine(ipMatch.Value)
Next
```

Comment: The Regex class also has Replace functionality. Works a treat for stuff like this.

Comment: yeah but with regex? what happens if the proxy is burried like <html><body>some test and then 1.111.111.11:80 some text </body>  

If i run a httpwebrequest to grab that html, the proxy is burried in text. So rather than have to have a custom function for every different scenario I wanna do like an Instring Check but use the reg ex expression. Is that possible?